# echo object property along with string in php order

Tags: php

```
<?php
class bankbalanced{
    public $banakbalance=100;
    public function showbalance(){
        echo $this->banakbalance;
    }   
}
$bb=new bankbalanced;
echo 'balance is:'.$bb->showbalance();
?>
```

in above code i tried echoing string along with property by an object.
why first
    $bb->showbalance() 
gets echoed, not balance is:
i am getting output as:'100balance is:'. but i want this to be formatted as 
balance is:100
first string then concatenation by object accessing property
thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Don't echo in showbalance function. Just return `$this->banakbalance`.

Answer (score 0):

`showbalance()` echoes the balance, it doesn't return it. So when you call the function, the balance gets echoed. Then the function returns nothing, which gets concatenated to the string `balance is:`, and then that concatenated string is echoed by the caller.

Another way to understand this is that

```
echo "balance is:" . $bb->showbalance();
```

is equivalent to:

```
$tempstring = $bb->showbalance();
echo "balance is:" . $tempstring;
```

When you write it that way, it should be clearer that the `echo` inside the function happens while calculating `$tempstring`, which is before that string gets concatenated and echoed.

You should do:

```
echo "balance is:";
$bb->showbalance();
```

Or you should change the function to return the balance instead of echoing it.

```
function getbalance() {
    return $this->banakbalance;
}

echo 'balance is:' . $bb->getbalance();
```

Comment: `echo` echoes its argument. But it doesn't get its arguments until after the function runs.

Comment: I've added some more explanation to the answer. You need to understand the order of operations when executing a statement that calls a function and does something with the result.